# converting from svg to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, svg

I'm trying to convert a svg file to a pdf with the following code, but got an error

src:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
drawing = svg2rlg("test.svg")
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "test.pdf")
```

error:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stone\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1446, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Stone\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1092, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Stone\Documents\FastDose\src\Beagle\Prove e test\test_renderpdf.py", line 9, in <module>
    drawing = svglib.svg2rlg("test.svg")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 1178, in svg2rlg
    svgRenderer.render(svg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 511, in render
    self.render(child, self.mainGroup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 534, in render
    item = self.renderG(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 626, in renderG
    item = self.render(child, parent=gr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 534, in render
    item = self.renderG(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 626, in renderG
    item = self.render(child, parent=gr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 534, in render
    item = self.renderG(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 626, in renderG
    item = self.render(child, parent=gr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 554, in render
    shape = getattr(self.shapeConverter, methodName)(n)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 875, in convertPath
    normPath = normaliseSvgPath(d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svglib\svglib.py", line 146, in normaliseSvgPath
    a = string.replace(a, 'e-', 'ee')
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined
```

Moreover I'd like to avoid hard-file and use StringIO to create a temporary svg/pdf file, but I guess that svg2rlg only accept a path as input.

Comment: Where is the rest of the error?

Comment: sorry cut&paste error...

Comment: It appears that there is a missing `import string` somewhere

Comment: I simply can't imagine why...

Comment: 1. Try to contact the svglib developers or fix the code yourself and send it to them  and create a pull request. 2. Here is something that uses [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) to generate pngs from svgs. You will need to change the file ending from ".png" to ".pdf" to make it produce pdfs. https://github.com/niccokunzmann/maglev-wiki-pictures/blob/master/svg2png.py#L51 Just install inkscape and maybe you need to add the path to the executable.

Answer (score 6):

For me to get it working was hand edit of:

```
/Users/<MY_USER>/.virtualenvs/<MY_VENV>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/svglib/svglib.py
```

and adding this missing

`import string`

Comment: yeah. that library is just old

Comment: by the way the latest [svglib](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/0.9.0/) fixes this